# Tomcat installation cannot specify JavaHome

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

I am trying to write a powershell script to install Tomcat9 on a Windows 10 machine.
Here is the command line I created.

Reference: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/setup.html

```
Invoke-Expression "C:\installer\apache-tomcat-9.0.41.exe /C=C:\installer\install-config /S /D=C:\Tomcat"
```

`install-config` file I created is like this:

```
JavaHome=C:\java
TomcatPortHttp=80
TomcatServiceName=My_Tomcat
```

`TomcatPortHttp` and `TomcatServiceName` work fine. However, instead of using the Java location I specified with `JavaHome`, Tomcat service uses the latest JRE it can find in Windows.

[image]

Is this a bug?
Does anyone know how to force Tomcat service to use the Java location in the config file?

Answer (score 1):

I have not verified it, but judging by the [Tomcat Windows Service Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) I would try to set the `Jvm` parameter with the full path to the `jvm.dll` on your system.

Comment: I guess I have to set `Jvm` after the installation, if I can not set it during the installation.